# Delphi 10.1 Firemonkey - Detecting the mouse click outside the component

Tags: delphi, mouse, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

How to detect the mouse click outside the component?
I'm making custom calendar and when clicking the TLabel with presented date - the TCalendar is appearing. It's working. But I want to disappear the TCalendar when mouse is outside the component and button is pressed? In VCL I might use the WindowsMessages, but there is a Firemonkey and I want to use it at iOS too.

BR

Comment: What about hiding the Calendar when it loses focus? All visual controls have an [`OnExit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.OnExit) event. Alternatively, when showing the Calendar, you might try calling its protected [`Capture()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.Capture) method (or set its [`AutoCapture`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.AutoCapture) property to true) so it captures all mouse events.

Comment: OnExit doesn't exists in FMX's TCalendar...

Comment: As I said earlier, **all visual controls have an [`OnExit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.OnExit) event**. It is inherited from `TControl`. And `OnExit` is definitely [**published in `TCalendar`**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.Calendar.TCalendar_Events). Check the declaration of `TCalendar` in `FMX.Calendar.pas` for yourself, you will see this is true: `TCalendar = class(TCustomCalendar) published ... { Events } property OnExit; ... end;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It gets mouse pos on screen (Win, iOs, Android). So you can use this to find when the cursor is out of your control. And for MouseDown try using MouseDown on Form.

```
function MousePos: TPointF;
var
  MouseService: IFMXMouseService;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXMouseService, IInterface(MouseService)) then
    Exit(MouseService.GetMousePos);
  Result := PointF(0, 0);
end;
```